# Why $_POST gets nothing from ajax request?

Tags: php, ajax, post

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = action;
httpRequest.open('POST','/fetch_product_list.php','true');
httpRequest.send("var=5");
```

but in the `fetch_product_list.php`, $_POST['var'] has nothing, How can I fix it?

Comment: It's there any reason why you are not using a library like `jQuery` ?

Comment: because headers are not set. add `httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: Also, is your path to the fetch_product_list.php correct?

Comment: @MihaiIorga sorry this is an assignment, I can't use jQuery,but it's also good to learn the foundation

Comment: @PLB thanks, it works! BTW why should I only put the line you provide after `httpRequest.open`? this any rule of order something?

Comment: @yozloy 1. Open connection. 2. Set data you want to send. 3. Send. That's why.

Comment: @PLB same thing like open a socket! thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included a content-type for the request body.

```
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Answer (score 2):

Add line: `httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` and hence the code looks like:

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = action;
httpRequest.open('POST','/fetch_product_list.php','true');
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpRequest.send("var=5");
```

and in php use: `$_POST['var']`.